# To use Dwolla with Mt. Gox I need to become Verified. Do I need Apostille?

Tags: mtgox, aml

Mt. Gox now requires at least Level 1 Verified in order to deposit or withdraw Dwolla funds.

Level 1 says Government Photo ID + utility bill

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox#AML
- https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20919111-aml-account-statuses

But then I see an update saying an apostille is needed.  Is that just for a Level 2 (Trusted) account?

- http://support.mtgox.com/entries/20861901-changes-to-aml-policies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An apostille is only required for level 2. Their original announcement of the change was confusing, but they have since clarified it on the forum - https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=60074.msg716245#msg716245.

Edit: You also need a bank account linked to your Dwolla account that has been verified over 30 days.

Comment: That is now true for transferring funds to Mt. Gox, but that 30-day requirement is not necessary when withdrawing funds from Mt. Gox.